# Informix: is it necessary to update statistics on views?

Tags: informix

In Informix I have a partitioned table for performance reasons.
One contains the latest data and another the historical data. Also, there is a view which contains data from both.

When I update statistics on the partitioned tables, do I also have to update statistics on the view?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to update statistics on a view in an Informix database.  Indeed, AFAIK, there's no way to do so; statistics are not stored for views.